# Presented SKScene changes back to start scene when changing the device orientation

Tags: objective-c, orientation, sprite-kit, skscene

i have a Problem with Sprite kit using more than one SKScene. Every time when I change the device orientation, sprite kit presents the first SKScene. When I flip the iPhone, the game scene disappears and the device is showing the menu scene.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank You for your help. I solved it with "`if ( !skView.scene ) {...}`":

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    if ( !skView.scene ) {  // <------- !! 

    SKScene * scene = [MenuScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    [skView presentScene:scene];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you run `presentScene` in the viewcontroller's `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method without safeguarding against the fact that this method will run repeatedly under certain circumstances, such as when the view is resized.